# Jessie RC2 installation on SDHC card

Tags: debian, sd-card

I am trying to install Debian Jessie RC2 (netinst) on a SD card on my laptop ([thinkpad t440p](https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Thinkpad/T440p/jessie)). When the hd partition stuff step comes I select manual partition. Unfortunately only the USB (from which I am running the installer) and internal HD appear in the list of partitionable HDs.

In addition I tried to see if with Ubuntu the same thing happened, but it was not the case: the SD card appeared.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Drop down to the console level and check the list of modules that are loaded in each case? My guess would be that support for this kind of hardware would be built on the module level. You could also look at the installation logs (during the installation) to see how that SD card is detected. How is the SD card attached to the laptop?

Answer (score 0):

To make the SD reader available in debian, you need to load the driver. 
for this you have to find out which driver is used by the ubuntu installer.

I did it this way:

```
$ lsusb
...
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
...
```

now use this name to find the log entry where the driver was loaded: 
(-C shows the context, ie 5 lines above and below)

```
$ dmesg |grep -C 5 Alcor
(nothing)
$ dmesg |grep -C 5 Multi
usb 1-6.3: Manufacturer: Logitech
usb 1-6.3: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
input: Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6.3/1-6.3:1.0/0003:046D:C050.0004/input/input9
hid-generic 0003:046D:C050.0004: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-6.3/input0
EXT4-fs (sdb2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Multi    Flash Reader     1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
init: ureadahead main process (238) terminated with status 5
init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (236) killed by TERM signal
init: lxcfs main process (311) terminated with status 1
```

Bingo. But in my case this does not give the driver name. :( lets try something else...

The device of your sd card (/dev/sdc in my case) has a major/minor number, this is the connection to the kernel driver. you can find out the major/minor number this way:

```
$ ls -l  /dev/sdc 
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 32 Aug 10 09:47 /dev/sdc
$ file /dev/sdc
/dev/sdc: block special (8/32)
```

so its 8 and 32. I don't know how to find out which driver this connects to, sorry. You have to find out yourself.

you may search the udev rules for this device. They define which driver is loaded for a Vendor/Product-ID. Use the Vendor/Product-ID from lsusb:

```
$ cd /lib/udev/rules.d/
$ grep -C -ri 058f *
$ grep -C -ri 6366 *
```

In my case this did not help in finding out which driver/module is responsible. :( Maybe it helps you...

If you found out which driver you need, just call `modprobe <module>` in debian. that should do it.

Comment: sorry for the late answer, have been busy and couldn't try what you suggested. The `lsusb` correctly shows the SD card under ubuntu, while under Debian the default ash shell would not run the command saying that there is no such command. Could it be that the netinst version of debian has a limited "set" of commands available?

Comment: try if you can install additional software in the debian installer with apt-get